# Free But Cannot Steal

Tags: riddle

Most people<sup>1</sup> have this. It's freely available too.

If you steal it, though, you are going to be in trouble with the law.

What is it?

**______**
<sub><sup>1</sup>*"Most" here is ~85% (Americans)*</sub>

Comment: "Most" here is ~85% (Americans), I should have been more specific.

Comment: There are too many possible answers to this, and no way of telling which one is correct.

Comment: I would agree with @bass, but its a good question

Comment: Ouch, I had a nice idea and was about to post an answer, and the question was closed just before I could post it. Well, I suppose I agree that there are too many possible answers. If only I had come 10 minutes earlier, or 10 minutes later... :-(

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is

> WiFi

Most people have this,

> Most American homes have WiFi at this point; the exact share varies a bit by source, but https://www.statista.com/statistics/457288/mom-wifi-home-access-usa/ indicates 83%.

... it's freely available too.

> Many businesses offer free WiFi to customers, and many communities and public places also offer free WiFi.

If you steal it though, you are going to be in trouble with the law.

> People have been arrested and prosecuted for WiFi theft; while the law isn't consistent from state to state, there are laws in most states that do make it a crime; see, for example,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_piggybacking#United_States
>  and https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/stealing-wi-fi-your-neighbor-a-victimless-crime.html

Comment: "you are going to be" is over-strong, though. Most who steal it are not caught. I guess "in trouble with" could be taken to mean "in violation of", but i usually interpret that as meaning being under investigation, being sought, or being charged by a law enforcement agency, under prosecution, or already convicted.

Answer (score 8):

Is it

> name/identity? Most people have a name, and you can change your name at will legally. But if you steal someone else's name/identity, you've done something illegal.

Comment: Only 85% of Americans?

Comment: @Scott this answer was posted before the OP added that comment.

Answer (score 7):

It's

> a life. Life is free, because you don't have to pay for it. Steal a life of another, and the law comes down on you. Everyone living has a life.

Comment: Thanks. How do you make it so that I dint spoil it?

Comment: It looks like this: >!insert hidden text here

Comment: Um... how do I do that... Im new

Comment: Just type the characters ">" and "!" at the beginning of your line.

Comment: I find this answer quite disturbing with the hint regarding 85% from OP... :P

Comment: Yikes I didnt even consider that

Comment: 15% of us have no life

Answer (score 7):

My guess is

> hair

because:

> Most people (but not all) have hair. It does cost anything to grow it. And if you steal hair from someone, that's illegal.

Comment: *Steal hair* Lol

Comment: gotta be hair, +1

Answer (score 2):

it is

> Rh+ blood

I know this because

> My wife is pregnant, and Rh+ vs - is an issue with pregnancy, so this is a recent research project that i have gone through hence knowing the percentage:)

Surely

> Stealing somebodies blood is illegal!

Comment: I wanted to donate blood, but they ask too many intrusive questions, like, "Where did you get this?" and, "Whose blood is this?"

Comment: @KSmarts I got it, uh, at the mall! I'm not exactly sure who's blood this is, but I can tell you they live 10 miles away, have 3 dogs, and blood type is B+!

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s

> Water, because it can be found in water fountains everywhere, but breaking into someone’s house and taking a drink is illegal.